# Are @Autowired or @Resource fields singletons?

Tags: java, spring

I'm maintaining an old application but am unfamiliar with Spring Framework. I'm working on a class that currently looks like this:

```
public class Foo {

    @Resource(name = "fb")
    private FooBar fb;

    @Resource
    private FooBar2 fb2;

    @Autowired
    private FooBar3 fb3 = null;

    ...
}
```

and an XML file that looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ... >
    <context:annotation-config/>
    ...
    <bean id="fb3" class="FooBar3"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

In some other method, the class Foo is instantiated:

```
void carryOutSomeFoobarring() {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    ...(use f)...
}
```

If carryOutSomeFoobarring is called at the same time from two different threads, there will, of course be two separate Foo instances of the local variable `f`. But will both instances of field `f.fb` refer to the same injected `FooBar` object? What about `f.fb2` and `f.fb3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Spring works by creating one instance of each bean.

You can think of them as all being created as the `ApplicationContext` initialises (in reality, depending on configuration, they might be lazily initialised later).

Then, when autowiring, it identifies the appropriate bean and injects it. If there is any ambiguity about which bean to use, an exception is thrown.

Beans can be configured as *prototype* beans - and for those, each time they are injected, a new instance is created. But that is not the default, and it's not all that commonly used.

However, Spring dependency injection only happens to Spring beans -- and beans are created by bean factories, not (directly) by `new`. Most of the time `new Foo()` will create an unmanaged instance of `Foo` -- not something managed by Spring, and therefore not something that will get fields injected.

So I would expect:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
return f.getFooBar();
```

... to return `null`.

This `Foo()` *might* subsequently get injected if higher up the call stack it was invoked by a method within an `@Configuration` class, called by Spring itself.

Answer (score 10):

By default they're singletons. If the scope is changed to prototype, you get separate objects.

Comment: Precise and concise. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you create Foo instances like you did:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

the local variables fb, fb2, fb3 will most likely be null. This is due to the fact that you create the Foo instance outside of the Spring application context and no wiring of the member variables will take place.

You should add a @Component annotation to the Foo class if it can be a singleton as well and make sure it is picked up by Springs Component Scan or create a seperate configuration class where you declare Foo as a @Bean

Comment: `@Component` and component scan is only one of the many ways that a bean can be defined. OP should probably do a bit of background reading on Spring.